# Find $\gcd(a,b)$ by sum of $ax + by$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have to represent the following gcd: $\gcd(315, 483) = 21$ by $\gcd(315, 483) = x\cdot315 + y\cdot483$.

Honestly, I have no idea how to start.

How do I get the $\mathbb x$  and $\mathbb y$?

Comment: Have you ever heard of Euclidean algorithm?

Comment: @MetinY. yes, I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Euclid's algorithm of calculating $\gcd$.

$483=1(315)+168$ ....$(1)$

$315=1(168)+147$....$(2)$

$168=147(1)+21$....$(3)$

$147=21(7)$....$(4)$

GCD$(483,168)=21$

Now we have, $168-147=21$

Use $(2)$ and substitute for $147$

$21=168-(315-(168)1) \implies 2(168)-315$

Now substitute for $168$ from $(1)$

$21=2(483-315)-315$

$21=2(483)-3(315)=483x+315y \implies x=2$ and $y=-3$.

Comment: Thanks !!!!!!!! this is a great example!!

Answer (score 1):

The [extended euclidean algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) gives them to you. Or you could use the euclidean algorithm to compute the GCD, and then go backwards substituting.

Comment: I missed the name. thank you very much! (I'll accept your answer in 7 minutes..)

Answer (score 1):

Reverse the steps in the [euclidean algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm#Worked_example) to express $\gcd(315, 483) = 21$ as sum of 315, 483 multiplied by $x,y$ respectively.

Alternatively find $z,w$ s.t. $z\cdot15+w\cdot23=1$ and use them to find $x,y$ ($315=15\cdot21, \ 483=23\cdot 21$).

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\ $ Canceling $\,21\,\,$ from $\rm\:315\, x + 483\, y = 21\:\Rightarrow\: 15\,x+23\,y = 1,\:$ so $\rm\ mod\ 15\!:\ 23\,y\equiv 1,\:$  $\rm\ y \equiv 1/23 \equiv 1/8 \equiv 2/16 \equiv 2/1,\ $ hence $\rm\ y = 2 + 15n,\ $ and $\rm\: x = (1\!-\!23y)/15 = (-45\!-\!23\cdot15n)/15 = -3-23n.$

Comment: Just a general question here, shouldn't the equation 315x+483y=21 have infinite integer solutions?

Comment: Oh, Mathgems, you got it done....

Comment: @imr As I wrote, the general solution is $\rm\:(x,y) = (-3\!-\!23n,2\!+\!15n) = (-3,2)+n(-23,15)\:$ for all $\rm\:n\in\Bbb Z.\:$ So, indeed, there are infinitely many solutions.